# Mail Is Not Being Synchronized Between Devices

Tags: icloud, mail.app, ios, ipados

Since the upgrade of iOS 13 and ipadOS, mail messages are not being properly synchronized. If I delete a message in macOS mail or the icloud.com web interface, it's not being deleted from the iPad and iPhone.

Logout from iCloud on iPad and iPhone didn't solve the problem.

Gil

Comment: Does the iPad and iPhone show account error in mail app? Do you check for "Last updated now" or similar?

Comment: No account errors. Mail shows Last Updated - Now.